# Sort Dictionaries in Array?

Tags: arrays, sorting

I need to sort an nsmutablearray of nsdictionaries, using a keyed object from the dictionary. The object is an NSNumber. How would I sort the dictionaries in the nsmutablearray with the first object being the highest nsnumber?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a custom comparator defined with a [block](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/Short_Practical_Guide_Blocks/_index.html) (you can go other ways but this is quite compact):

```
NSComparator mysort = ^(id dict1, id dict2) {
    NSNumber n1 = [dict1 objectForKey:@"key"];
    NSNumber n2 = [dict2 objectForKey:@"key"];
    return (NSComparisonResult)[n1 compare:n2];
};

[yourArray sortUsingComparator:mysort];
```

Comment: This is efficient, but why am I using 2 dictionaries (dict1 and dict2?)?
Also how should this code be used?, in a for loop? I want to get every nsnumber from each nsdictionary in the array. Will this do that?

Comment: The good thing about custom comparators is that you don't need to use them. Once you defined a function that is able to provide a total ordering over a set of elements, the sorting implementations of Cocoa will automatically manage the sorting by using that function.. when you call `sortUsingComparator:` everything will be done by Cocoa itself.

Answer (score 1):

That code seems a bit off. Here is one that works.

```
[theMutableArrayThatWillBeSorted sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSNumber* n1 = [obj1 objectForKey:@"key"];
    NSNumber* n2 = [obj2 objectForKey:@"key"];

    return [n1 compare:n2];     
}];
```