# ios sort array with dictionaries

Tags: ios, sorting, dictionary, nsmutablearray

I have an NSMutablearray, populated by dictionaries [from a JSON request]

i need to organize the array depending to a key in the dictionaries

the dictionary

> ```
> IdReward = 198;
> Name = "Online R d";
> RewardImageUrl = "/FileStorimage=1206";
> WinRewardPoints = 250;
> ```

so the array is composed by different dictionaries with the above form, and I need to organize  by maximum to minimum  `WinRewardPoints`

I have seen    [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951048/sort-dictionaries-in-array) in SO, but dont understand yet how to adopt it for my case,

thanks a lot!

Comment: Which part of that answer confused you?  That answer is correct and very simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
IdReward = 198;
Name = "Online R d";
RewardImageUrl = "/FileStorimage=1206";
WinRewardPoints = 250;


NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (int i=0; i<[dict count]; i++) {
    [arr addObject:[dict valueForKey:@"WinRewardPoints"]];
}

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:nil ascending:YES] autorelease];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
arr = [[arr sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors] copy];


NSMutableArray *final_arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for(NSString* str in arr)<p>
{
    for(int i=0 ; i<[dict count]; i++)
    {
            <t>if ([str isEqualToString:[[dict valueForKey:@"WinRewardPoints"]objectAtIndex:i]]) 
                            {

                [final_arr addObject:[dict objectAtIndex:i]];
            }
    }

}

NSLog(@"%@",final_arr);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
// create a NSString constant for the key we want to sort by, so we don't have to create more NSString instances while sorting
static NSString* const keyToSortBy = @"WinRewardPoints";

// sort an array that contains dictionaries, each of which contains a NSNumber for the key defined "WinRewardPoints"
[yourArray sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSNumber* n1 = [obj1 objectForKey:keyToSortBy];
    NSNumber* n2 = [obj2 objectForKey:keyToSortBy];
    return [n1 compare:n2];
}];
```